# I want to open an existing profile in chrome and then open some website but the problem its Throws some error related chrome crashes

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

Error statment = The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.

Here code snippet

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys   import  Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by  import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t

def selenium_config():
    options = Options()
   options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/VIBHAS DUTTA/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile 3")
    options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 3")
    driver_manager = ChromeDriverManager()                
    chrome_service = Service(driver_manager.install())                       
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=options)
    return driver


driver = selenium_config()

# driver.get("https://www.google.com")
while True:
            audiotext = input("Enter: ")
            if "search" in audiotext:
                audiotext = audiotext.replace("search", "")
                element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
                element.clear()
                element.send_keys(audiotext)
                element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

i have tried by add more arguments and options but its not working i have searched youtube thats not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the crash error but it still not open the profile i want to open

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).